# How to alter table with SQL CE on Windows Phone 7?

Tags: linq-to-sql, sql-server-ce, windows-phone-7

Let say I deploy a v1.0 of a WP7 with a SQL CE database. In the version v1.1 I need to add a new column to one of the table.

What is the recommend way to do that ? Is there a way to detect if the column exists and create it if needed ?

Thanks,
Jeremy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the DatabaseSchemaUpdater class if you are adding columns etc - see this MSDN article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh394022(v=VS.92).aspx